# ggplot2: secondary axis on the same side as the primary

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to put the secondary scale in `ggplot2` on the same side as the primary one? (I'm talking about a secondary axis that is a one-to-one transformation of primary axis, so I avoid problems outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/3915051), the issue is purely the placement of the scale.)

Example:
[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible unless you want to mess around with the gtables/grid

Answer (score 0):

could solve what you want ?

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = cty))+
  facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think it answers the question (honestly, I don't really see if it has anything to do with the question at all...). Please compare the result of this answer with the example (and my overall aim).